# ubuntu 14.04 not detecting external hdd ext4

Tags: 14.04, external-hdd, ext4, format, detect

I have a 3TB external hard drive that I have formatted to ext4 using gparted. Now when I plug it into my laptop ubuntu doesn't detect it at all. This is the fdisk output

```
    sudo fdisk -l

    Disk /dev/sda: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
    255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders, total 234441648 sectors
    Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disk identifier: 0x000df52a

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
    /dev/sda1   *        2048   226254847   113126400   83  Linux
    /dev/sda2       226256894   234440703     4091905    5  Extended
    /dev/sda5       226256896   234440703     4091904   82  Linux swap
```

dmesg | tail -n 20 output

```
    dmesg | tail -n 20
    [106774.182191] usb 4-4: Product: Elements 107C
    [106774.182195] usb 4-4: Manufacturer: Western Digital
    [106774.182198] usb 4-4: SerialNumber: 574D43344E3045383039544E
    [106774.182536] usb-storage 4-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
    [106774.183401] scsi7 : usb-storage 4-4:1.0
    [106775.181274] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       Elements 107C    1065 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
    [106775.181741] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
    [106775.187553] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
    [106776.188533] .........ready
    [106784.390768] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] 732558336 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
    [106784.391090] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
    [106784.391095] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 53 00 10 08
    [106784.391344] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
    [106784.391348] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through 
    [106784.391968] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] 732558336 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
    [106784.527729]  sdb: sdb1
    [106784.529341] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] 732558336 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
    [106784.556111] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
    [106786.598431] EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
    [106798.837322] usb 4-4: USB disconnect, device number 3
```

lsusb output

```
    lsusb

    Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b2e1 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate   Matching Hub
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
    Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0489:e032 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this somehow?

Comment: use `lsblk` to list the disks. it actually looks like it's a western digital device plugged into the usb port, correct?

Comment: i just plugged it in, mounted it formatted to ntfs, but now when i try to unmount it gives me this error

Unable to find block device for drive.

Comment: Just got it working with the umount command

Comment: Awesome. Whenever you format or reformat a partition or drive, it needs to unmount to do the formatting and after formatting, the drive will not be visible. Usually, you can just unplug the device and plug it back in to automount whenever you are done. Also, you can answer your own question and accept your own answer as the solution to close it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got it working with the umount command